# Google Colab 環境で keras==2.2.4 のインストールが出来ない

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

google colabで下記のバージョンにインストールしてから

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.14.0
!pip install keras==2.2.4
!pip install tqdm
```

各ライブラリーをimportすると

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

import keras
print(keras.__version__)

import tqdm
print(tqdm.__version__)
```

下記のエラーが発生しました。

```
1.14.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-caa506f695aa> in <module>()
      2 print(tf.__version__)
      3 
----> 4 import keras
      5 print(keras.__version__)
      6 

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/initializers/initializers_v1.py in <module>()
     19 
     20 
---> 21 _v1_zeros_initializer = tf.compat.v1.zeros_initializer
     22 _v1_ones_initializer = tf.compat.v1.ones_initializer
     23 _v1_constant_initializer = tf.compat.v1.constant_initializer

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v2.compat' has no attribute 'v1'
```

1ヶ月ほど前はこのエラーが出てなく問題なく動作していたんですが
本日いきなりこのエラーが発生しました。

これに関して解決策がありましたら、ご教示願います。

Answer (score 1):

Google Colaboratory では既に TensorFlow や Keras がセットアップされていて、以下の magic command を実行すると利用可能になります。

```sh
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```

[image: magic command]

Comment: おかげで問題なく実装出来ました。ありがとうございます。